# emacs24 on mac cursor movement is quite slow

Tags: macos, emacs

Recently I began to use Emacs on Mac OS instead of Ubuntu, but one thing annoys me so much is that cursor movement is much slower than that in Ubuntu.
Specifically, when I use c-n, c-b, c-f, c-p, the cursor moves slow, any idea about this issue?
Btw, both the separate gnu emacs 24 and start emacs within terminal have the same issue.

Comment: It looks like you have an answer you're happy with, so you need to 'Accept' the answer.

Answer (score 14):

By default, the cursor movement is globally very slow in OS X. You can tweak it in "System Preferences" -> "Keyboard". Try to adjust the "Key Repeat" and "Delay Until Repeat" until you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

This is an OS level key repeat setting issue

The UI to change this is in "System Preferences", but you can go even faster by going around the UI.

See ( https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx#L139 ):

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it really works. I just change it through 'system preferences'